# Can not find script file "Z:\Scripts\LiteTouch.wsf"

Tags: wds, mdt

I installed and configured MDT 2013 yesterday on server 2012. I have a WDS also. I am able to create a WIM file. I did PXE boot into a test virtual machine and I was able to install Windows 10. My MDT is also on vmware ESXI. MDT server is joined to my domain.

I created a task sequence with "sysprep and capture". On the vm that I want to capture I mapped the deployment share and I tried to run the "`LiteTouch.vbs`" I got the following error:

```
Can not find script file "Z:\Scripts\LiteTouch.wsf"
```

I am confused because "`LiteTouch.wsf`" is just below the vbs file.

This is the first time I am trying to capture an image on the newly built MDT.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or what I can do to resolve this.

Comment: Are you running this under the local administrator account, or a domain account?

Comment: @RobbieCrash on virtual machine I want to capture I am logged in as local admin, but I mapped the deployment share using domain admin credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The file share to the WDS server has been created wrong. Remove the file share. Then open an elevated command prompt and use:

```
net use z: \\servername\deploymentshare$
```

and it will work as expected.

Another issue is you cannot create an image of a computer joined to a domain.
It has to be in a workgroup.